# Illustrate Meaning of : gcc -g programName.c

Tags: c, debugging, compilation, gcc

To debug a C program using **gdb** effectively it is required to compile it first using the command:

```
gcc -g programName.c
```

otherwise on using simply

```
gcc programName.c
```

and running we are unable to provide **gdb** the Source Code i.e.*programName.c*
resulting in an error message -

```
dl-debug.c: No such file or directory.
```

on demand for command like *list* in **gdb**.

Please Explain the Cause, Why it is like this.

Comment: Have you read the manual or did any other research, yet?

Comment: the `-g` flag tells the compiler to add debug info that allows gdb to function, it is disabled by default to 1 prevent bloat and 2 prevent reverse engineering

Comment: @ratchetfreak it doesn't really prevnt reverse enginieering, maybe it adds a tiny bit of work, but there's still enough info in the binary and good tools ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A debugger needs:

- to refer to variable and function names, not their addresses (e.g. `i` not `0xdeadbeef` and `main()` not `0x4B1D`).
- to associate the address of machine code with a line in the source code.

To this purpose the compiler builds (`-g`) a (augmented) symbol table (it may be embedded into the program or stored as a separate file). Sometimes other ancillary information are generated.

There are different formats to store these information (stabs, coff, dwarf...).

Contrarily to popular beliefs, many compilers (GCC for sure) write **some** symbols to an object file even in release mode (with the -O3 switch).
That's why even with a release binary, you can do:

```
$ gcc -O3 programName.c
$ gdb a.out
[...]
Reading symbols from a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Of course this isn't enough for a good *debugging experience*.

Symbols can be removed from the binary using the strip command:

```
$ strip -s a.out
$ nm a.out
nm: a.out: no symbols
```

and now:

```
$ gdb a.out
[...]
(gdb) b main
Function "main" not defined.
```

Also consider that there is an interaction between code optimization and debugging:

- some variables you declared may not exist at all;
- the flow of control may briefly move where you did not expect it;
- some statements may not be executed because they compute constant results or their values were already at hand
- some statements may execute in different places because they were moved out of loops
- ...

So, with many compilers, you [cannot turn on both optimization and debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69250/3235496) (GCC has the [-Og switch](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for debugging optimized code).

Further details:

- [Preparing An Executable For Debugging](http://rsquared.sdf.org/gdb/paefd.html)
- [Options for Debugging Your Program](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)